# Event on SFDC Public Calendar not showing on Contact Activities list

Tags: contact, calendar

I have a public calendar to which everyone in the org has Show Detail access. When I add a new event to the calendar and set the "WhoId" equal to a Contact, the event does not show up on the Open Activities or Activity History list on the Contact Detail page.  Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: Are you applying that change via the API or in APEX code or via the UI?

Comment: I've tried it via the UI and Apex and the result is the same. It doesn't show up in the Open Activities or Activity History related lists for the Contact

Answer (score 3):

Found this in the Salesforce Knowledge base.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000181946

> How can my Public Calendar events show up on the Open Activity related
>   list?
>
> Knowledge Article Number: 000181946
>
> Description Some customers would like for their Tasks/Events in their
>   Public Calendar to be linked to a specific record.  Also for those
>   Tasks/Events to show up in the Open Activity related list on the
>   record detail page.
>
> Resolution At this time, Public Calendar events do not show up at the
>   record level in the Open Activity related list
>
> Workaround: Customers should use the Calendar on their home page to
>   enter events they want to show up on the record level.
>
> Suggestion: Customers requesting this functionality can also be
>   directed to vote for an existing Idea on the Ideas Exchange.
>   https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpN0AAK